2nd Conditional & Modals (What modals are possible)
With the 2nd Conditional, we normally use 'would,' 'could,' or 'might' in expressing an unlikely present or future outcome.
Is it possible to use other modal verbs?
For example,

If found a bag with a 1000 euros, I ... /
If I were you, I ...

Am I able to use can / should / May ?? Thank you.

Can you give a more specific example? There are a lot of real-world cases where conditionals don't match the forms taught in ESL class (and there's subjunctive "had I...", but "had" isn't a modal). But if you're formally studying English and you're taught how to do 2nd conditionals, you should do them how you're taught (at least until you've finished that module).

Hi Stuart. For example: can, may, should... Would you kindly elaborate on "Had I..." Thank you for your input.

No, Alexander, Stuart didn't mean "please give examples of some verbs you are thinking of": he meant examples of actual complete sentences.

If found a bag with a 1000 euros, I ...  / If I were you, I ... Am I able to use can / should / May ??  Thank you.

I took the liberty of editing your comment into the body of the question. In the future, when questions need extra clarification, add it in the question itself, since comments aren't always permanent, and so that the question contains everything it needs to be answered.

I'll let someone elaborate, but the answer is no, except maybe for usage #5 of "should" here.

You need to provide a full sentence.

We say 'a thousand euros', but the article isn't needed before numerals - 1000 euros or €1000.
